# Subtle meaning of 「役目を果たす」

Tags: meaning, phrases

I just wonder what does 「役目を果たす」 mean exactly? I know that this phrase roughly means "to perform one's duty". But does it also imply that the duty at issue will be fulfilled and so will be exempted in the future, or does it have no such connotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

役目を果たした does imply that the role that was given is now fulfilled, and that it will not be performed anymore. E.g. if you say 役目を果たしたタイヤ then the implication is that the tyre has expired and cannot be used anymore.